# Key-on electrical for the Honda NC700x

Tags: honda, electrical, motorcycle

I've got a 2014 Honda NC700x motorbike, and I'd like to install the aftermarket Bikemaster Heated Grips on it. I purchased the 7/8" kit, instead of the 1" kit that is also offered.

When it comes to connecting electrical components to the NC700x, I've been seeing a lot of talk about a "subharness" and a "relay." Are these components absolutely necessary, to connect external accessories, or can I get away without them?

Is the "subharness" and "relay" designed to ensure that connected accessories are only powered while the ignition is on?

Any help understanding this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use a switch to turn on the heating then you definitely should use a relay, wiring the switch in directly is not a good idea. Usually switches shouldn't ever see high currents that are used in such applications, so switching should be done via relays only. If you don't need an on/off switch for your grips - a relay could allow you to turn the grips on and off together with other devices, for example your headlights (so they wouldn't turn on as soon as the ignition is turned on but rather when the lights are switched on). If you want so simply wire it directly to the ignition then it should be alright without a relay, but it's quite impractical - you have no way of turning the heating off, even in hot summer days.

As I understand the subharness is basically wiring for the grips along with the connectors, you could just fabricate your own, but some kind of wiring is obviously necessary.

Comment: Yeah, good points mate. I did a ton of research, and discovered power distribution modules like PDM60, Fuzeblocks, and others. These relay + distribution blocks seem like the right way to go, so I'll avoid getting the official subharness and relay.